# Mongoid sorting on custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sorting, mongoid

I have an object method called 'likes' in my model which will  give total number of likes for an object. Now I want to sort this model based on total likes . How can we achieve this in Mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that's a problem. You can't do that using mongoid. Mongoid orders objects based on their fields. Now if you save the 'likes' for every object in a field, fine, it's straightforward:

```
Model.desc(:likes)
```

If not, you'll have to use [map/reduce](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/querying.html#map_reduce), which is way more complicated for a simple case (in my limited point of view) like this. But of course I don't know your app, so maybe it compensates.

Answer (score 1):

More to the essence of the issue,
you can't achieve this in nearly all client-server environments,
it's the nature of client-server processing.
You can't arbitrarily mix client-side and server-side processing and state.
It's extremely rare to have Ruby on both sides of the client-server divide,
and even rarer to have transparent processing across the divide.

In this case, you can't mix your client-side 'likes' method in Mongoid/Ruby
with server-side query sorting implemented in C++ by the MongoDB server.
Your only choices are to be compatible with existing state and processing that are available on one side or the other.

On the client-side,
you can fetch the data into Ruby objects and then sort in Ruby using your 'likes' method.
This is subject to efficiency issues for the amount of data fetched and the cost of the 'likes' method for sorting.
If the count of your documents is non-trivial,
you will want to 'memoize' the result of the 'likes' method into your data before sorting
so that the 'likes' method is not called for every comparison in the sort.

On the server-side,
you can re-implement your 'likes' method in code that the MongoDB server provides,
either the aggregation framework
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/
or map-reduce
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

As stated by Tiago Farias, if you can store the result of 'likes' in each document,
then you can easily sort by that field in your Mongoid/MongoDB query as he specifies.